# ImageView не отображается в Drawer header

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer, imageview

В не отображается значок аккаунта в drawer header - все остальные элементы отрисовываются. Всё инициализируется. Никак не могу понять, в чём проблема. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

drawer_header.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150sp"
        android:background="#f4f6f8">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="101sp"
            android:layout_height="90sp"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/avatar"
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.051"
            android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="300sp"
            android:layout_height="26sp"
            android:id="@+id/emailview"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_marginTop="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Code]
[image: DrawerD]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить `tools:srcCompat="@drawable/avatar"` у компонента `ImageView` на `android:src="@drawable/avatar"`.

В свойствах `android:layout_width`, `android:layout_height`, `android:layout_marginTop`, `android:layout_marginStart` лучше использовать `dp` вместо `sp`.

Comment: Это сработало, спасибо.
Почему стоит использовать dp?

Comment: @thepotion33, потому что sp-для размеров текста. Их реальное значение в пикселях вычисляется на основе заданных юзером на уровне системы размера шрифтов на девайсе. На dp эта системная настройка не влияет.